# PostgreSQL Basic Authentication with SSL = on

Tags: ssl, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

In PostgreSQL with Password authentication , if SSL = on , in postgresql.conf file , then can the client connect without the SSL certificate on his side ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling SSL (SSL = on) will still allow both normal and SSL connections. However, the pg_hba.conf file can be configured to allow only SSL (or both) through using the hostssl and clientcert option.  See here [for more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html)